# Reduce/eliminate RenderTexture temp buffers in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, textures, render

While checking the memory profiler from Unity's Bitbucket, I found a massive `RenderTexture` taking up more than 300mb of memory. When I looked at the details, I found this:

[image]

This wasn't the only one but its the biggest. Is there anyway to delete them, or at least reduce the number of temp buffers?

Edit: Here is a picture of it, The entire app takes up about 1gb or so

[image]

Comment: something doesn't seem right, 3072 x 1680 in RGBA is only 20mb, how did you measure something 10 x larger?

Comment: @zambari I have no idea but I added a pic of it just in case its useful. There are a couple of them and they're all huge

Comment: Are you using deferred shading rendering path?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, so I don't think I am.